# Templated Param Type in Templated Member Function

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

So I have a simple struct used for template definitions.

```
    template<class T>
    struct EventListener
    {
        typedef Functor<T, void, Event*> functor;
        typedef void (T::*FunctionPtr)(Event* evt);
    };
```

and in a class I have a function

```
    template<class T>
    void addEventListener(const string &eventName, T* target, EventListener<T>::FunctionPtr function);
```

When I try and build this (VS2010, Windows 7, x64)

I get the following error:

```
    Error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FunctionPtr'
```

I feel like this should be valid.

If I replace the T in the function declaration with a specific class...

```
    template<class T>
    void addEventListener(const string &eventName, T* target, EventListener<Foobar>::FunctionPtr function);
```

...The code compiles.

And if I replace the typedef with the actual type...

```
    template<class T>
    void addEventListener(const string &eventName, T* target, void(T::*function)(Event* evt));
```

...it also compiles.

So what am I missing here? I am pretty sure that the latter example will suit my purposes, but I would rather keep it in a typedef.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the `typename` keyword:

```
template<class T>
void addEventListener(const string &eventName, T* target, 
                      typename EventListener<T>::FunctionPtr function);
```

otherwise the C++ parser is mandated by the standard to interpret `FunctionPtr` as a static method, enum, or data-member, etc. in the `EventListener` namespace, not a `typedef`.

Comment: +1, as of the parser cannot tell part, the standard mandates that `FunctionPtr` is interpreted as a member and not a nested type.